# Conditional formatting in item view (display form) using CSR / JS / CSS - is it doable?

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-form, formatting, conditional

Is it possible to apply conditional formatting to an item view [Display-Form] just like in the list?

I use SharePoint Online, Cisar and SharePoint extensions for Chrome.

Comment: depends on the condition, but I wouldn't see why not. Why can't you use some jslink/javascript? Have you looked into that?

Comment: The CSR is nothing but a javascript code which you can combine with any condition. What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Based on date and other fields fields, to change the background colour if the value meets certain criteria, but as usual, Danny's solution is perfect. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to take into account that the `ctx` object is different for Views and Forms:

This CSR code works in both View and Form (*no need for a 90KB jQuery library*):

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

  function colorStatus (ctx) {

    var item = ctx.CurrentItem || ctx.ListData.Items[0];// View OR Form

    var value = item.Status;

    var color = { 'Not Started' : 'lightgreen',
                  'Closed'      : '#FFF1AD',
                  'In Progress' : '#FFD800',
                  'Active'      : '#01DF3A' } [ value ];

    return String.format("<span style=background:{0}>{1}</span>" , color , value );
  }

  function init() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      Templates: {
        Fields: {
          "Status": {
            View: colorStatus,
            //EditForm: colorStatus,
            DisplayForm: colorStatus,
            //NewForm: colorStatus
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/colorstatus.js"), init);
  init();
});
```

---

**Remember!** You do have to apply the JSLink to both the View and the Form

**use the fabulous WYSYWIG CSR [Cisar editor](https://365csi.nl/cisar)**

iCSR iSTATUS

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint Online, you should be aware of the JavaScript/CSS customization is not allowed for the `Modern Experience` list and libraries. Meanwhile, it's allowed for `Classic Experience`.

In case, you are using `Classic Experience`, you can apply conditional formatting via Jquery in `Display form` based on a **specific field value** via the below code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('h3:contains("Status")').closest('td').next('td').text().indexOf('In progress') != -1)
{
$('h3:contains("Status")').closest('tr').css("background-color", "green");
}
else
{
$('h3:contains("Status")').closest('tr').css("background-color", "red");
}
});
</script>
```

For the detail steps, check [CONDITIONAL FORMATING IN SHAREPOINT DISPLAY FORM VIA JQUERY](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/10/01/conditional-formating-at-dispform-aspx-via-jquery-in-sharepoint/)